# Vuejs conditionally render nav items after authentication

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, single-page-application, vuetify.js

I'm creating a SPA using vuejs with vuetify and authenticating with a laravel/passport api. I'm having a hard time nailing down the conditional rendering of my nav icons. Obvs I want them to not be visible to unauthenticated users and then to show when the user is authenticated and redirected to my main page. Here is my App.vue that has the v-app and nav:

```
<template>
  <div>
<v-app>
  <v-navigation-drawer app absolute v-model="drawer"></v-navigation-drawer>
  <v-toolbar app color="primary" class="white--text">
    <v-toolbar-side-icon @click="drawer = !drawer" dark></v-toolbar-side-icon>
    <v-toolbar-title>App</v-toolbar-title>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
      <v-tooltip bottom>
        <v-btn
          flat
          to="/"
          slot="activator"
          dark
          v-if="showNav"
        >
          <v-icon>home</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <span>Dashboard</span>
      </v-tooltip>
      <v-tooltip bottom>
        <v-btn
          flat
          to="/SubmitBug"
          slot="activator"
          dark
          v-if="showNav"
        >
          <v-icon>add</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <span>Submit a new Bug</span>
      </v-tooltip>
      <v-tooltip bottom>
        <v-btn
          flat
          to="/logout"
          slot="activator"
          dark
          v-if="showNav"
        >
          <v-icon>close</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <span>Logout</span>
      </v-tooltip>
    </v-toolbar-items>
  </v-toolbar>
  <v-content>
    <v-container fluid>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-container>
  </v-content>
  <v-footer class="pa-3 white--text" color="primary">
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <div>&copy; {{ new Date().getFullYear() }} SomeCoolCompany</div>
  </v-footer>
</v-app>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    drawer: false,
    showNav: false
  }),
  beforeCreate () {
    User.checkAuth() ? this.showNav = true : this.showNav = false
    console.log(this.showNav)
  },
  created () {
    EventBus.$on('logout', () => {
      User.logout()
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

And here is the User.js helper that is actually doing the api call:

```
import AppStorage from './AppStorage'
import Auth from '../models/Auth'

class User {
  login (creds) {
    axios
      .post('/oauth/token', {
        grant_type: 'password',
        client_id: 2,
        client_secret: 'secret',
        username: creds.username,
        password: creds.password
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setAuth(response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
  }

  setAuth (data) {
    const token = new Auth(data).accessToken
    AppStorage.store(token)
  }

  checkAuth () {
    if (AppStorage.getToken()) {
      return true
    }
    return false
  }

  logout () {
    AppStorage.clear()
    window.location = '/'
  }
}

export default User = new User()
```

The console log in the `beforeCreate` hook is logging true, but I have to refresh to get the icons to show. The `User.checkAuth()` returns a boolean. If I place the `User.checkAuth() ? this.showNav = true : this.showNav = false` in the created method, it initially logs false, but then true on refresh. Anyone know a graceful way to handle this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a getter for it, beforeCreate doesn't matter here because the elements aren't available anyway, so using a getter makes the most sense as it will fire only when the component is available:

```
computed: {
  showNav() {
    return User.checkAuth()
  }
}
```

Comment: Same issue. `showNav` is false on initial render and then true if you refresh.

Comment: My first attempt was to just set `showNav: User.checkAuth()` since it's just a boolean, but that has the same issue.

Comment: I'll also add that they become unshown on logout, which is based on that same check. Logout just clears the local storage, in that same User.js helper class.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, figured this out by calling `window.location = '/'` in my User.js login method, rather than `this.$router.replace('/')` in the login component's login method. Timing is everything.